# Styling in D3 with a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js, styling

I wonder if it possible to use styling actions on the same element many times? I got this Array called A which stores 3 colours and I want to go through a loop that fills my element link.

```
var A = ["blue", "red", "green"]

    for ( var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){


                link.style("stroke", function(d) 
                {

                   return A[i];



                 }
                 ) 
                };
```

Comment: So, have you run the code and tested if it is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I feel that this is an x,y problem. Your code will style the nodes in `link` three times in a row, but fast enough you will just see them as green, no? Or are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: yep, only the color of the last element (green) of the Array is shown on screen. Why is that?

Comment: @ Teemu: It works, but only the last element of the Array gets active. That means, all links get green.

Comment: It shows as green because each time it loops through it changes the color of all the nodes in `link`, and each time that color replaces the color from the previous iteration of the loop. Are you trying to style links sequentially? ie: First link is blue, second red, and third green?

Comment: yes, I try to do it sequentially, but don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style each link a different style based on the index of that element/datum in the selection. As with many things in d3, this does not require a loop. You can access the index of each datum with code like:

```
selection.attr("property",function(d,i) {
  return array[i];
})
```

For sake of ease, I've used some circles and fill rather than links and stroke, but the method is identical. The snippet below will color links sequentially based on the colors array.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300);
  
var data = [[50,50],[100,50],[200,50],[300,100]];
var colors = ["steelblue","orange","pink","red"]

// create some circles:
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d+")"; })
  .attr("r",10)
  
// to style sequentially, you can use the datum's index:
circles.attr("fill",function(d,i) {
  return colors[i];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Which part of the code makes it possible? Is it `.attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d+")"; })`?

Comment: That line just positions the circles in one line of code (rather than with cx, cy), it is based on the data in the data array. If using the index, it is based not on the data, but on data order as done here: `circles.attr("fill",function(d,i) { return colors[i]; })` where `i` is the index of each element(circle in this case) in the selection.